How does spark determine the number of partition to create in a RDD during its initial data load?
I was using Pyspark interactive shell with following
Python version 3.12.4
Spark : 3.5.1
I tried to read a csv file of size 910MB and tried to query the number of partitions in it.
The commands were :
rdd_csv = sc.textFile("/path/to/my_csv_file")
rdd_csv.getNumPartitions()

The answer it gave for number of partitions was 28.
I want to know how spark decide on how many partition should it create?
Here are the spark configurations:
spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes : 134217728b (128 MB)

spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes : 4194304b (4MB)

sparkContext.defaultParallelism : 8

My expectation was that it should create 8 partitons by using the formula
number of partitions  = File_size/maxPartitionBytes = 910 MB/ 128 MB = 7.1 \~ 8

Since the number of partition is equal to defaultParallelism. Spark should not try to reduce the partition size below 128 MB.
However, upon inspection it splitted the file into rhougly 33 MB file size giving a total of 28 files or partitions.
I want to know why it created 28 partitions instead of 8 partitions.
